# Android text field: distance between line and text

Tags: android, layout

Google Material Design recommends to align items so that text falls on a 4dp baseline ([source](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-baseline-grids)). It also recommends specific paddings between elements.

I am a designer and I think working with these principles really helps to have a clear and visually pleasing layout. However, the developers in my team are having trouble to turn the designs into code.

An example: Take In a single-line text input field. According to Google Material Design (and my design) the distance between the line at the bottom should be 12dp. The developer says it is not possible to control the distance between the line and the text. Is this true? If so, Google's design guidelines propose a behaviour that can't be implemented by Google's very own Android APIs.

[image]

On one hand, I don't want to make the devs' lives unnecessarily hard. On the other, the appearance of an app really gains a lot when distances  are not set arbitrarily.

I have a background in web development where vertical rhythm is a common problem. In fact the problem is so common that a couple of approaches are documented to solve it ([example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/aesthetic-sass-3-typography-and-vertical-rhythm)). Isn't it the same with Android?

On a more general note, how much design fidelity can I expect from the developers? Can you point me into the right direction where they can look for solutions to this problem?

Comment: try `TextView#setLineSpacing`

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:paddingBottom="12dp"` on your EditText.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my take on the issue: When you specify the dimensions of `x dp` units, you basically say the dimension should be `x px` on a `160 dpi` screen. If the screen is `240 dp`, the dimension will convert to `x * 1.5 px`. In a nutshell: `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`.

Now, with the vast number of devices in the Android ecosystem, be assured that decimal px units will ALWAYS creep-in. Android has its own ways for resolving these, which is what is probably happening in the screen above. For a unit as small as `12dp`, the system is bound 'eat' a few pixels in an attempt to translate the dimension for individual screens.

By the way, being both a developer and a designer, I can confidently say that your developer mentally stabbed you if you asked him to find ways to change the height between the bottom line and text.

Comment: This is not an issue of pixels beings swallowed when rounding. I look at Dropbox' sign-up form and it conforms to the specs. On the same phone I look at the build my developer gave me and it doesn't.