# Android: Align button in app bar vertically with app bar title

Tags: android

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164978/android-text-field-distance-between-line-and-text) about vertical rhythm in Android UIs.

Google Material Design allows a button at the top right of an app bar ([image source](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior)):

[image]

Note how "New event" and "SAVE" sit on the same baseline.

Based on these guidelines I created the following design:

[image]

The developer in my team tells me there is no way in Android to align the title text with the button on the right. So this is what it looks like in the app:

[image]

Is it true that the button at the top right cannot be aligned vertcally and horizontally?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but to me even in the first image "Save" seems smaller so it gives the illusion that it's on the same baseline, but you sure can create a bar however you like it..it is just has to be a custom xml aligning it on the top of the screen that it will act as a bar

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you. Do you think Google created a custom xml for the example in the Google Material Design guidelines? (We try to minimize custom components to have more maintainable code.)

Also, the font sizes are definitely different. Buttons are always 14sp, titles are 20sp. Nevertheless the text should be aligned on the baseline.

Comment: You are welcome, i do not know if Google used a custom xml,i understand your thinking about "trying to minimize custom components" but from my point of view, sometimes creating your own xml as you like it and not implementing "ready" components could be better, especially if you don't need all the futures of the component, which will make your custom xml lighter. In this particular example, creating a relative layout would definately work as a charm, and you could align perfectly whatever you like.